# Google Sheets Appscript Send Email if any of the Dates in 3 columns = today

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to write a code that will automatically trigger an email if either column C , D or E (dates) equals today's date, I've been doing some research on Or logical operators for Js but is not working, I'm getting a "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" error, is it either on the condition for today or is it because the Or operators (||) ?

**Updated Script**  This now is working fine defining today's date using const currenttime = new Date(), but I'm getting an email for each line item instead of just those with today's date, any clues?

```
function sendEmails() {
  const sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    const sheet = sheet1.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange("A1:E1000");
  const data = dataRange.getValues();
  const currenttime = new Date();

  data.forEach(function (rowData) {
    const recipient = rowData[0];
    const emailAddress = rowData[1];
    const Notes = rowData[5];
    const date = rowData[2];
      const date2 = rowData[3];
        const date3 = rowData[4];

    if (date == currenttime || date2 == currenttime || date3 == currenttime) {return}

    const greeting = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n'
    const customerMessage = 'Please follow up with ' + Notes + ' By today!';
    const greatJobMessage = 'Thanks';

    const message = [greeting, customerMessage, greatJobMessage].join('\n');
    const subject = 'Reminder to Follow up!';
    MailApp.sendEmail("ecmoranavila@gmail.com", subject, message);
  }) 
}
```

Comment: it should be without comma like : if (date = today() || date2 = today() || date3 = today()) {
      return
    }

Comment: I've tried that as well and I'm getting a _ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment (line 15, file "Code.gs")_ error

Comment: So, I was able to get it to work, I needed to define the today() which is '''new Date(); on a constant, the new code , however I'm not getting an email for only the one line that has today date but I'm getting an email for each line item, any thoughts?

Comment: Can you update the code you posted with the new working one? Also, do you get an email for each line, even if it's not the today date?

Comment: Updated, yes I'm getting an email for each line instead of just those with today's date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with your script that need to be addressed in order for it to work.

First of all, your `if` condition is not doing anything. It has an empty return (?) and then it gets closed. The code that sends the email is out of the condition so it will always run.

Second, the Date declaration returns an string like this: `Fri Mar 13 12:30:50 GMT+01:00 2020`, so it is not useful unless the dates in your Sheet should also specify hours, minutes and seconds (miss one second and the email will not  be sent).

---

**Fixes:**

1. Get the data of the Sheet with [getDisplayValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues). Otherwise the script will get the date in a completely different format than the Sheet:

   `const data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();`

   In my Sheet, the dates look like this: `13-03-2020`, but you can use any other [format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

---

2. Format the Date of the current time. As I said before, `new Date()` returns a long String. You can format it with the [Utilities class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) to make it coincide with the dates written in the Sheet:

   `const currenttime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'UTC', 'dd-MM-yyyy');`

---

3. Change your `if` condition so it covers the rest of the code. Also, remove the `return` as it's not doing anything:

```
  if (date == currenttime || date2 == currenttime || date3 == currenttime) {

   const greeting = 'Dear ' + recipient + ',\n'
   const customerMessage = 'Please follow up with ' + Notes + ' By today!';
   const greatJobMessage = 'Thanks';

   const message = [greeting, customerMessage, greatJobMessage].join('\n');
   const subject = 'Reminder to Follow up!';
     MailApp.sendEmail("ecmoranavila@gmail.com", subject, message)}
 }); 
}
```

Comment: Working as expected,  thank you for the clarification on the '''return